# Cant scrape a webpage with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html

I am new to python. Now I want to scrape the information from inc.com.
url is http://www.inc.com/profile/ultra-mobile
I want the everything possible in that chart. However, when I tried to scrape this html, it doesn't show the information.
the code is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
section_url = "http://www.inc.com/profile/ultra-mobile"
html = urlopen(section_url).read()
```

the result is

```
<div id="MainPatternContainer" class="PatternContainer">
</div>
```

the actual one is

```
<div id="MainPatternContainer" class="PatternContainer">

<div id="MainPatternContainerSubUnit0" class="PatternContainerSubUni
    showLoadMore loading"><div id="MainPatternContainerSubSubUnit0" 
    class="PatternContainerSubSubUnit "><div class="leftBorderMask"></div>            
    <div class="rightBorderMask"></div><div class="Inc5000ProfileTile  
    PatternTile Default Inc5000ProfileDefaultConfiguration" id="Tile-39">
    <div class="profile" id="company36631" style="min-height: 1330px;">
    <div class="responsive">
......................................................
</div></div></div></div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This page use JavaScript to generate all elements on page so beautifulsoup can't get it. You need Selenium or something similar.

Comment: Thank you, furas. I will try.